# Fantasy story with main character traveling by a small stolen submarine down a river

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember starting a fantasy novel decades ago with the main character traveling by a small stolen submarine down a river. He has many adventures in and out of the sub.

I recall small creatures that lived under the water that were killed and used as tobacco.

Answer (score 6):

This is a long shot but there is a small possibility that this is *The Stone Giant* by James Blaylock. It was published in 1989, so fits your timescale of decades ago (unless you could clarify on how many decades ago, 2, 3, 4?) and features a submarine stolen or accidentally acquired from a pirate who I recall as some sort of magical creature. Adventures then ensue. I recall small creatures underwater that I think were referred to as Henny Pennymen, can't say if they were used as tobacco though as I no longer have my copy. There are more details on this book at this wikipedia entry. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stone_Giant
See if it jogs any additional memories.

**Edit:** excerpt from Chapter 9 of *The Stone Giant* (emphasis added)

> Escargot angled **the submarine** in for a closer look. It was a curious business, kelp at that depth. And the bubbles themselves seemed to be creeping about, or rather womething within them was creeping about. They quite clearly weren't empty. He squinted through the glass, imagining that he heard a distant tinkling sound, like glass windchimes in a feeble little breeze. One of the kelp strands lazied along through the water toward the window of the submarine, as if the kelp were as interested in him as he was in it. It edged up against the window, and Escargot found himself looking into **the tiny face of a henny-penny man.**
>   
> The hands of the little man were thrust through the sides of the bubble, as if he wore the bubble as an altogether suit with the pantlegs cut off at the knees, and in one hand he held a tiny rock hammer. He was altogether human, tiny as a field mouse, but with a jowly, elongated face that seemed to owe a good deal to fish ancestors of one sort or another. Escargot had always wondered if henny-penny men wore clothes. There was no reason to suppose otherwise, really. Everyone else did. It made it seem about twice as ghastly, however, that **horrible Uncle Helstrom smoked the bones of these poor devils in his pipe.** It was like smoking an elf. He'd heard—or rather he'd read in Smithers—that henny-penny men lived in the sea, and that they migrated upriver to spawn, then drifted back down again on leaf boats and on pieces of bark. But he'd had no idea that they mined fire quartz.

[image]

Comment: wow! great find.Thank you.  No need to alter at all. Just hope it is actually the correct book, but it looks accurate.